# mongo db recovery no backup present

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

We have no backup stored in /data/backup dir, also files present in /data/db is from 15th July.

We have checked the collections in dbs found  document starting from 15th July.

this is standalone mongo db, no replica set configured.

Is there any way to recover the db,  to restore all the documents  present before July 15th in Mongo db.

We have below  files present in /data/db dir, frm which file we can check previously used path, and how can we restore from these collection files, any suggestions, thanks.

How can we open these files also  and restore it data before 15th July.

We have not removed any documents from collections, only .WT files are not present before 15th July, which we want to restore, is there any way from above files.

Comment: Not sure what the question is?

Comment: Thanks Joe, Is there any way to recover the db, to restore all the documents present before July 15th in Mongo db? we don't have backup present in /data/backup dir.

Comment: Probably not.  WiredTiger reuses the free space in the data file, so once the documents are removed the blocks are overwritten.  The best case scenario here is that on 15 July the configuration was somehow changed to a new dbpath, and there is a different directory that contains the data prior.

Comment: Thanks Joe, i have  added the files present in /data/db, can you please suggest how can we recover data  before from 15th July.

Comment: Not from that.  Is there another directory that also contains .wt files?

Comment: Can we find  from the files present in : /data/db dir with names like wired:-WiredTiger
WiredTiger.lock
WiredTiger.turtle
WiredTiger.wt
WiredTiger.wt.orig
WiredTigerHS.wt    
WiredTigerLAS.wt

Comment: We have checked all other dir, in size we found only /data/db dir  only consuming more space then any other mount point.

Comment: I would say: no backup - no mercy. It is already difficult to start the database when a single `.wt` file is missing or corrupt - even when it is just an index file which in principle could be generated from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Domscheit,  any suggestion how to find the  if there any dir change from above wt files, also from this wt files how can we restore the dbs, thanks.

Comment: can we restore the db from above files present in /data/dab. we have seen files from 15th july to till date, but not bofore 15th july files in /data/db dir.

Comment: Thanks Joe, Wernfried, can you please suggest how can we recover db from these above wt files present in /data/db dir.

Comment: You would need to determine which of the files belong to the collections you currently have.  Then, if there are any unaccounted filed,  look in the WT code to learn the file format so you can examine those other files to see what they contain.

Comment: Thanks Joe,  can there be conflict in current set of data while restoring from /data/db dir.....also could you please provide steps how can we automate mongodump backup from aws portal.